Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to DepthwiseConv2D: {'groups': 1} error when loading the .h5 model in tensorflow colab
I'm trying to load this face anit-spoofing model. It is a MobileNetV2 model. I want to convert it to coreML format. I have uploaded the .h5 model file into the colab. But when I try to load the model using tensorflow I get this following error.

ValueError: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to DepthwiseConv2D: {'groups': 1}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Here is my python code to load the model and print the model summary. The tensor flow version in Colab 2.17 I have downgraded it to 2.16 because I found this API documentation for DepthWiseConv2D for tensorflow version 2.16. But still the same error occurs. Here is my code
import tensorflow as tf
import coremltools as ct


model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/MobileNetV2.h5')
print(model.summary())

When I run the code it gives me this error

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/ops/operation.py in from_config(cls, config)
    233         try:
--> 234             return cls(**config)
    235         except Exception as e:

16 frames
ValueError: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to DepthwiseConv2D: {'groups': 1}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/ops/operation.py in from_config(cls, config)
    234             return cls(**config)
    235         except Exception as e:
--> 236             raise TypeError(
    237                 f"Error when deserializing class '{cls.__name__}' using "
    238                 f"config={config}.\n\nException encountered: {e}"

TypeError: Error when deserializing class 'DepthwiseConv2D' using config={'name': 'expanded_conv_depthwise', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'kernel_size': [3, 3], 'strides': [1, 1], 'padding': 'same', 'data_format': 'channels_last', 'dilation_rate': [1, 1], 'groups': 1, 'activation': 'linear', 'use_bias': False, 'bias_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'bias_regularizer': None, 'activity_regularizer': None, 'bias_constraint': None, 'depth_multiplier': 1, 'depthwise_initializer': {'class_name': 'GlorotUniform', 'config': {'seed': None}}, 'depthwise_regularizer': None, 'depthwise_constraint': None}.

